# Securityproblem when running Win XP on Virtual Box/Ubuntu after april 8.?

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a securityproblem if I run my WinXP on Virtual Box in Ubuntu after april 8.? I have configure my guestcomputer to communicate with my main computer via shared folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch malware into your virtualbox system, it can destroy or infect files in shared folders. If you explicitly added real HDDs to virtual machine, than malware can corrupt that HDD and any other OS that uses it. Finally, if you have network between guest OS and host OS, malware can try hacking and bruteforcing your host machine. 
As long as you have proper setup on host machine and nothing useful or executable in shared folders, it is safe as can be.